# How to create an array starting and end in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create a weight array that starts at 40 and ends at 140 like this:

```
const weight = [
  {
    label: '40 Kg',
    value: '40',
  },
  {
    label: '41 Kg',
    value: '41',
  },
  {
    label: '42 Kg',
    value: '42',
  },
];
```

I have tried this snippet but does not work for me:

```
const weight = [...Array(10).keys()].map(i => i + 30);
```

how i can do this? thanks in advance

Comment: With a `for` loop.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic?

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz something like this:  const heightnum = [...Array(10).keys()].map(i => i + 30);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const weights = [...(Array(101).keys())].map(i => ({label: `${i + 40} Kg`, value: `${i + 40}`}));
```

That's just your idea taken one step further to create the proper structure. Note: You need round braces around the body of the arrow function as it would otherwise interpret the curly braces of the object structure as "function-body" instead of as a return value.

The more straight-forward option to achieve this array of objects structure would be like this:

```
const weights = [];
for (let i = 40; i <= 140; i++) {
  weights.push({
    label: `${i} kg`,
    value: `${i}`,
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, why is ended in 139 not 140?

Comment: Ah sorry, my fault. Array(100) creates 100 elements starting at key 0. Your question asked for 101 elements starting at 0 and ending at 0

Answer (score 0):

You can create like this

```js
const weights = Array.from({ length: 10 }, (v, i) => {
  // write your custom logic here
 return { weight: i + 1, name: `${i + 1} kg` };
})

console.log(weights)
```

Or you can create from a predefined array like

```js
const weights = Array.from([40, 50, 60], (v) => {
      // write your custom logic here
     return { weight: v, name: `${v} kg` };
    })

    console.log(weights)
```

Comment: The first one it's working for me, but how i can make it start from 40 not from 1?

Comment: instead if `i + 1` you can write any expression e.g. ` i + 40` or `2 * i + 10` or `3 * i + 20`

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's many ways, here's two of them:

```js
weight = []

for (i= 40;i<=140;i=i+1){

 weight.push({
  label: i + ' Kg',
  value: i.toString()
 })
}

console.log(weight)
```

```js
a = 40
b = 140
weight = []

while (a <= b){

 weight.push({
  label: a.toString() + ' Kg',
  value: a.toString()
 })

 a += 1
}

console.log(weight)
```